# Missing text in pdf, Covington, TeXShop, XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, pdf, texshop, covington

The abbreviated covington portion of the sample below will not come out in the pdf.

It use to before I tried a different Devanagari font.

Please help.

TIA!!

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec} %xltxtra,xunicode}
%\usepackage{tipa}
%\usepackage{polyglossia}
%\usepackage{etoolbox}
%\usepackage{pdfsync}
\usepackage{covington}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip} 
\font\I="Devanagari MT" at 14pt 
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Charis SIL}

\title{}
\begin{document}
\date{}
\maketitle


\I{स्वेच्छाकेसरिण: स्वच्छस्वच्छायायासितेन्दवः}\\
\I{त्रायन्तं वो मधुरिपो: प्रपन्नर्तिच्छिदो नख:}
\medskip

\textrm{svecchākesariṇaḥ svacchasvacchāyāyāsitendavaḥ\\
trāyantāṃ vo madhuripoḥ prapannārticchido nakhāḥ}

\textrm{svecchā-kesariṇaḥ svaccha-svacchāyā-āyāsita-indavaḥ\\
trāyantāṃ vo madhuripoḥ prapanna-arti-cchido nakhāḥ}
\medskip

\begin{example}
\glll {svecchā-} 
{begin.cmpd}
{own wish} 
\glend
\end{example}

\end{document}

This is XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.3-0.9997.5 (TeX Live 2011)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./Untitled.tex
LaTeX2e <2009/09/24>
Babel <v3.8l> and hyphenation patterns for english, dumylang, nohyphenation, ge
rman-x-2009-06-19, ngerman-x-2009-06-19, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ibycus, arabi
c, armenian, basque, bulgarian, catalan, pinyin, coptic, croatian, czech, danis
h, dutch, ukenglish, usenglishmax, esperanto, estonian, ethiopic, farsi, finnis
h, french, galician, german, ngerman, swissgerman, monogreek, greek, hungarian,
 icelandic, assamese, bengali, gujarati, hindi, kannada, malayalam, marathi, or
iya, panjabi, tamil, telugu, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, kurmanji,
 lao, latin, latvian, lithuanian, mongolian, mongolianlmc, bokmal, nynorsk, pol
ish, portuguese, romanian, russian, sanskrit, serbian, serbianc, slovak, sloven
ian, spanish, swedish, turkish, turkmen, ukrainian, uppersorbian, welsh, loaded
.
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size12.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/expl3/expl3.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/expl3/l3names.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etex-pkg/etex.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/expl3/l3basics.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/expl3/l3expan.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/expl3/l3tl.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/expl3/l3int.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/expl3/l3quark.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/expl3/l3seq.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/expl3/l3toks.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/expl3/l3prg.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/expl3/l3clist.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/expl3/l3token.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/expl3/l3prop.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/expl3/l3msg.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/expl3/l3io.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/expl3/l3skip.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/expl3/l3box.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/expl3/l3keyval.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/expl3/l3keys.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/expl3/l3precom.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/expl3/l3xref.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/expl3/l3file.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/expl3/l3fp.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/expl3/l3luatex.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xpackages/xbase/xparse.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kastrup/binhex.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-patches.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fixltx2e.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/euenc/eu1enc.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/euenc/eu1lmr.fd))
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xunicode/xunicode.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg))
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/covington/covington.sty
* covington.sty : Covington's linguistic macros, 2001 March 27 *
) (/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cancel/cancel.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/parskip/parskip.sty)
(./Untitled.aux)

LaTeX Warning: No \author given.

[1] (./Untitled.aux) )
Output written on Untitled.pdf (1 page).
SyncTeX written on Untitled.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on Untitled.log.
```

Comment: Wow, time flies!  Best way to do these days?

Answer (score 2):

Even if this answer comes way too late for the OP, for the record: You are missing the terminating and mandatory `\glt` command in the gloss:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec} %xltxtra,xunicode}
%\usepackage{tipa}
%\usepackage{polyglossia}
%\usepackage{etoolbox}
%\usepackage{pdfsync}
\usepackage{covington}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip} 
\font\I="Devanagari MT" at 14pt 
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Charis SIL}

\title{}
\begin{document}
\date{}
\maketitle


\I{स्वेच्छाकेसरिण: स्वच्छस्वच्छायायासितेन्दवः}\\
\I{त्रायन्तं वो मधुरिपो: प्रपन्नर्तिच्छिदो नख:}
\medskip

\textrm{svecchākesariṇaḥ svacchasvacchāyāyāsitendavaḥ\\
trāyantāṃ vo madhuripoḥ prapannārticchido nakhāḥ}

\textrm{svecchā-kesariṇaḥ svaccha-svacchāyā-āyāsita-indavaḥ\\
trāyantāṃ vo madhuripoḥ prapanna-arti-cchido nakhāḥ}
\medskip

\begin{example}
\glll {svecchā-} 
      {begin.cmpd}
      {own wish}
\glt
\glend
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

Or, if you use the macros introduced with `covington 2.0`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec} %xltxtra,xunicode}
%\usepackage{tipa}
%\usepackage{polyglossia}
%\usepackage{etoolbox}
%\usepackage{pdfsync}
\usepackage{covington}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip} 
\font\I="Devanagari MT" at 14pt 
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Charis SIL}

\title{}
\begin{document}
\date{}
\maketitle


\I{स्वेच्छाकेसरिण: स्वच्छस्वच्छायायासितेन्दवः}\\
\I{त्रायन्तं वो मधुरिपो: प्रपन्नर्तिच्छिदो नख:}
\medskip

\textrm{svecchākesariṇaḥ svacchasvacchāyāyāsitendavaḥ\\
trāyantāṃ vo madhuripoḥ prapannārticchido nakhāḥ}

\textrm{svecchā-kesariṇaḥ svaccha-svacchāyā-āyāsita-indavaḥ\\
trāyantāṃ vo madhuripoḥ prapanna-arti-cchido nakhāḥ}
\medskip

\trigloss[ex]
   {svecchā-} 
   {begin.cmpd}
   {own wish} 
   {}

\end{document}
```